# AJAX Form not AJAX submitting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm working on a login form using AJAX and jQuery, however the form is not submitting the right way: it is going to process.php instead of returning me a message on index.php.

**index.html**

```
<form id="login" action="process.php" method="POST">

    <div id="name-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="JohnDoe">
    </div>

    <div id="email-group" class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="john@doe.doe">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>

</form>
```

Nothing wrong found in the form. At least I couldn't find any errors there.

**index.html; this is the JS AJAX script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // process the form
    $('#login').submit(function(event) {

        // get the form data
        // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
        var formData = {
            'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
            'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val()
        };

$.ajax({
    type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
    url         : 'process.php', // the url where we want to POST
    data        : formData, // our data object
    dataType    : 'json' // what type of data do we expect back from the server
})
    // using the done promise callback
    .done(function(data) {

        // log data to the console so we can see
        console.log(data);

        // here we will handle errors and validation messages
        if ( ! data.success) {

            // handle errors for name ---------------
            if (data.errors.name) {
                $('#name-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                $('#name-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.name + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
            }

            // handle errors for email ---------------
            if (data.errors.email) {
                $('#email-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                $('#email-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.email + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
            }

        } else {

            $('form').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + '</div>');
            alert('success');

        }

    });

});
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
$errors         = array();      // array to hold validation errors
$data           = array();      // array to pass back data

    if (empty($_POST['name']))
        $errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';

    if (empty($_POST['email']))
        $errors['email'] = 'Email is required.';

    // if there are any errors in our errors array, return a success boolean of false
    if ( ! empty($errors)) {

        // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['errors']  = $errors;
    } else {

        // if there are no errors process our form, then return a message

        // DO ALL YOUR FORM PROCESSING HERE
        // THIS CAN BE WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO (LOGIN, SAVE, UPDATE, WHATEVER)

        // show a message of success and provide a true success variable
        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['message'] = 'Success!';
    }

    // return all our data to an AJAX call
    echo json_encode($data);
```

I'm almost pulling my hair out, please help me out what is going wrong.

Comment: I am assuming you are including correctly all of the JS files in index.html, correct?

Answer (score 0):

you are submitting the form twice one one clicking the submit button and one on the AJAX function - you need to stop the default submission so that the AJAX one can function:

edit your JS to include the following:

```
 $('#login').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
//rest of code
```

Comment: Somehow not working for me, it still puts me on process.php

Comment: @J.Doe Check your Javascript console, make sure it's not getting an error.

Comment: @Barmar This script is not understandable for me anymore so I have taken a more simple script from the interwebs, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Form Submit event so you can prevent it form redirection to the other page by

```
return false
```

at the end of the submit function

like....

```
$('#login').submit(function(event) {
     // your code
    return false;
}
```

and if still not working then you may need to try this

```
$(document).on('submit','#login',function(event){
    // your code
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @
Shah Khalid - typo on sumbit :))

Comment: The second form would only be needed if the form is added to the document dynamically.

Comment: @Barmar sorry for misspelling.